# Soap-error Parsing Schema: can't import schema from unexpected targetNamespace

Tags: php, python, soap

I have a PHP Soap-Server.
When a (for example) python-suds script is asking the WSDL it gets it correct.
The WSDl does import an XSD that's located somewhere on the same site.
Also this goes well, as python can use the factory to create the type that is defined in the imported xsd.
When the request is handled with client.service.ActionName() the PHP script starts.

PHP initializes its own wsdl first, and then gets an error on the import of the xsd located on his server.

Short question: why can python load the xsd import while php can not?

Here you have the beginning of the wsdl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:tns="http://---/webservices/2012-09/" xmlns:eba="http://---/schemas/1-0/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema/" targetNamespace="http://---/webservices/2012-09/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/">
<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://---/webservices/2012-09/" elementFormDefault="qualified">
        <xsd:import namespace="http://---/schemas/1-0/" schemaLocation="xsd/XSDName"/>
    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

this is the beginning of the xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="ElementName" type="ElementType">
```

This is the Python script:

```
url = 'http://---/wsdl&' + str(uuid.uuid1())
client = Client(url)

print client

wb = client.factory.create('ns0:MyType')
print wb

post_result = client.service.RequestFunction(wb)
```

This is the PHP script:

```
$soapServer = new SoapServer('http://---/wsdl'); // <-- fails here
$soapServer->setClass('SoapHandler'); 
$soapServer->handle();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two obvious differences:

1. in PHP you're using SoapServer instead of SoapClient
2. in Python your URL is different than in PHP - you add some userid or something like that /wsdl& + str(uuid.uuid1()) vs. /wsdl